# Additional column settings missing for comments column under core document columns

Tags: column

I have 3-4 columns with "multiple lines of text" field type in the "core document columns" group. While all of them have the full range of options available for setting the number of lines or the type of text (rich text, plain text) and have the full range of options available the comments column is missing these options.

Can anyone help me out

PS. I need a reputation of 10 for being able to post the snapshot.

Answer (score 1):

Columns in the "Core Document Columns" group are used by SharePoint for its OOTB features (Content Types, etc.). One particular reason for the Comments column is that is used by example in the Publishing pages - which can only accept Plain text (by design).

The column is marked as not editable, this being the reason why you cannot change.

Hope it helps,
C:\Marius

Answer (score 0):

I think Marius has already answered your question here in that the Comments column in the Core Documents group is a "sealed" column which therefore means you won't be able to update it.  The column is used by other content types within SharePoint so it's best to leave it alone and create your own for your own use.

I also wanted to clarify that it's not used by the content types you get with Publishing enabled - this is a separate "Comments" column added to a special SharePoint group called "_Hidden" (which is hidden in the UI) but does have the same display name (the Publishing one, however, does allow Rich Text and is not sealed whereas the Core Documents one does not).